# How can I install Ubuntu on an Acer Nitro 5?

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, acer

I'm trying to install Ubuntu. I have a bootable USB, but when I change from the boot menu the device which I want to boot from, from SSD to my USB, it shows me a black screen and I select **Install Ubuntu"** and then while the Ubuntu icon runs it freezes (the icon and the process too).

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: After the boot it asks for language, click next, on the keyboard layout screen it just hangs indefinitely. Please help.

Comment: Is your GPU NVIDIA?

Comment: NVidia GeForce GTX 1050Ti with 4GB Dedicated GDDR5

Comment: I know what is the problem. In ubuntu 18 you can’t install it if you have an Nvidia GPU. I resolved it making an usb with ubuntu 16, but after installation of the OS , when you arrive at the login screen and try to login , it freezes. You will need to reboot and start ubuntu in recovery mode(you can search on the internet a tutorial). After you loged in, you will have to go to “Software and Updates” ==> “Additional Drivers”. If you are an Nvidia user, it will appear the driver for your Nvidia GPU. If I’m not wrong, the driver for Nvidia is set on X.org.X server etc. Now set the other option of

Comment: Continuation: driver as the default( I think there are two possible drivers). Reboot the machine and run Ubuntu in normal mode. Idk why ubuntu uses a non-proprietary driver, but this should resolve the issue.

Comment: Did you installed ubantu ? I've got the same problem please help

Comment: Yes, use the instructions below.

Comment: you need to add nomodeset to grub boot parameter see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu).

Comment: you need to add nomodeset to grub boot parameter see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Live USB for installation does not boot, visual artifacts on purple splash screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077486/live-usb-for-installation-does-not-boot-visual-artifacts-on-purple-splash-scree)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From comments:

> You can't install Ubuntu 18 if you have an Nvidia GPU. I resolved it making a USB with ubuntu 16, but after installation, when you arrive at the login screen and try to log in, it freezes. You will need to reboot and start Ubuntu in recovery mode. After you logged in, you will have to go to **Software and Updates > Additional Drivers**. If you are an Nvidia user, it will show the driver for your Nvidia GPU. If I’m not wrong, the driver for Nvidia is set on X.org.X server etc. Now set the other option of  driver as the default (I think there are two possible drivers). Reboot the machine and run Ubuntu in normal mode.

Answer (score 1):

When in the GRUB boot screen, type e to edit the startup script. Search for the line containing `quiet splash` somewhere near the end, and add the following after `splash`:

`acpi=noirq pci=noacpi ivrs_ioapic[4]=00:14.0 ivrs_ioapic[5]=00:00.2`

You'll need to repeat this every time you boot, until you finally get a running system. Then you may edit `/etc/default/grub` and add the above to the variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. On my system it looks like this:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=noirq pci=noacpi ivrs_ioapic[4]=00:14.0 ivrs_ioapic[5]=00:00.2"`

After you save and exit the file, you'll need to run `update-grub` to apply the changes, afterwards you should be able to boot normally.

By the way, I didn't manage to get a proper installation with 18.10, but it worked fine with 18.04.1.

Answer (score 0):

1. Re-partition your drive to make room for Ubuntu using the *Windows Disk Management* tool to shrink the main Windows partition.
2. Open a command prompt as administrator.  Enter `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal`
3. Reboot the system and enter the BIOS Setup via <kbd>F2</kbd>.  Change the SATA Operation mode from Optane to AHCI.  Save changes and exit BIOS.
4. The system will reboot and should automatically boot into Windows 10 safe-mode. Once in Windows safe-mode, open a command prompt as administrator again.  Enter `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot`
5. Reboot with Ubuntu USB
6. Boot into Ubuntu Live by selecting *Try Ubuntu* during the boot process.
7. Press <kbd>E</kbd> in order to edit the install command you are about to run. Go to the line that starts with word `linux` (the one with the words quiet splash), go to the end of this line and after the `---` put the following words: `nouveau.setmode=0`.
8. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot the system
9. Run the Ubuntu desktop installer as *Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager*. If you have enabled *third party drivers*, you may not need steps 10-14 below.
10. After install, boot Ubuntu in recovery mode
11. Choose *Enable network* and then "root"
12. Run `add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`
13. RUN `apt-get update`
14. RUN `apt-get install nvidia-390`
15. Exit and you should be done.

Answer (score 0):

Just select install Ubuntu safe mode.
Connect to internet while installing, as it will download the necessary drivers also.
Hope this helps.
Regards,
S. Sakthivel

Comment: Sometimes the Ubuntu installler does not install the necessary drivers even if you tell it too, but you can still install the drivers from the terminal after you reboot and it will work.