# Live USB for installation does not boot, black error screen followed by visual artifacts on a purple screen

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, acpi, nomodeset

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 desktop with Rufus on a computer with the following specs:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2600
- MOBO: ASUS Prime B450M-A/CSM
- RAM: G-Skill Ripjaws DDR4 F4-2400C15D-16GVB
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX750
- PSU: Apexgaming AG-650M
- SSHD: Seagate Firecuda Compute
- mATX: Rosewill SCM-01

Basically it boots from the USB (FAT32) and brings up a black error screen with words and numbers. Then it transitions to the purple splash screen with "ubuntu" and 5 dots, however the screen shows various visual glitches depending on which USB port I plug into.

When trying to boot the computer, it boots to a black screen with the following error message:

```
ACPI Error: Needed [Integer/String/Buffer], found [Region]
```

[Here's a YouTube video](https://youtu.be/1hMWySNdegg) that shows what I mean.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try selecting the [`nomodeset` boot option](https://askubuntu.com/tags/nomodeset/info) to tell the kernel to not start video drivers until the system is up and running.

From the purple ubuntu screen press the <kbd>F6</kbd> key. If you don't see this screen, shutdown, boot from the Ubuntu live USB again, and immediately after the motherboard / computer manufacturer logo splash screen appears when the computer is booting, with BIOS, quickly press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, which will bring up a GNU GRUB menu screen. With UEFI press (perhaps several times) the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to get to the GNU GRUB menu screen. Sometimes the manufacturer's splash screen is a part of the Windows bootloader, so when you power up the machine it goes straight to the GNU GRUB menu screen, and then pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> is unnecessary.

If you see a screen that looks like the menu in the third screenshot, then scroll down to the next section (**Enable nomodeset from GRUB boot menu**) and follow the instructions in that section instead.

[image]

After pressing F6, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on nomodeset and an "x" will appear to the left of the option. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to leave the popup menu. The selections are retained at the time the user presses the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. Then use the down arrow key to highlight the **Install Ubuntu** option and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to select it.

[image]

---

The below section is intended to be used when the menu in the first screenshot does not show when booting from the Ubuntu live USB. Otherwise follow the instructions in the first section.

#### Enable nomodeset from GRUB boot menu

**Safe Graphics Mode**. A new option is added to the GRUB menu in 19.04 and later which will boot with `nomodeset` on. This may help you resolve issues on certain graphics cards and allow you to boot and install any proprietary drivers needed by your system.

Immediately after the motherboard / computer manufacturer logo splash screen appears when the computer is booting, with BIOS, quickly press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, which will bring up a GNU GRUB menu screen. With UEFI press (perhaps several times) the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to get to the GNU GRUB menu screen. Sometimes the manufacturer's splash screen is a part of the Windows bootloader, so when you power up the machine it goes straight to the GNU GRUB menu screen, and then pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> is unnecessary.

You will see a GNU GRUB menu screen that looks like this:

[image]

Press <kbd>e</kbd> to enter editing mode. This will bring up a GNU GRUB screen that looks like this:

[image]

Use the arrow keys to navigate when screen editing the above screen. Navigate to after the string on this screen that starts with `root=`. In this example screen the full string is `root=` followed by `UUID=` and a hexadecimal string as shown below:

```
root=UUID=bcf15ef2-a0b2-4753-9558-8399dd12a729
```

Immediately after this string replace `ro quiet splash` by `nomodeset quiet splash`. This change is only temporary — it will just be used once and GRUB won’t remember it in the future. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot with the `nomodeset` option that was added. If you make a mistake, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to go back to the previous screen.

To make the change permanent you need to add it to the `/etc/default/grub` file. Append `nmodeset` inside the quotes of the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="..."`. Then update your grub settings with `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Is this purple screen what you are talking about? trying to attach photo [link](https://imgur.com/bKAyA6u)

Comment: After pressing F6, I pressed enter on nomodeset and an "x" appeared to the left of the option. I pressed escape and then I am brought back to the first image.

Comment: I pressed enter on "Install Ubuntu" and it brought me to the install page where I have seen on the video. It asks for language, keyboard settings, time zone and credentials. Solved! Thank you Karel

Comment: My GNU Grub screen looks like the third example. But when I hit 'e', I get completely different strings, there was a "casper quiet splash" that I changed to "nomodeset quiet splash", then rebooted, but then no GRUB screen, just throws errors.

Comment: @gracious1 That's all the `nomodeset` options that I've got, so it's safe to say that the `nomodeset` kernel boot option doesn't help you to boot to the Ubuntu installer USB in your situation. [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689258/)

Comment: Instead of just giving me a link you could tell me how you think it is relevant to my situation. I have read the answer, don't really understand it, and I'm not sure it will work since I do not have "old ,slow" USB on a brand new laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same issue upgrading my pc with new CPU, Motherboard, GPU and Ram.

Ryzen 7 7200X CPU
Tuf B450 Motherboard
EVGA 1660 Super

I ended up having to take out the 1660 and put my old GPU EVGA 970 in to get a display, and then downloaded the 1660 drivers from EVGA.  After I did that I was able to reinstall the 1660 and reboot with success.  Everything seems to be running smoothly now.