# Ubuntu 18.04 Will Not Run w/o nomodeset

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, display-resolution, nomodeset

So here's the situation.

I purchased my computer parts, assembled them and booted up as far as the BIOS. However, the splash screen would display with graphical errors so I followed the instructions in this link (The computer parts are here as well):

[LINK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077486/how-can-i-fix-this-ubuntu-install-error/1077489#1077489)

I can run Ubuntu w/ nomodeset enabled but I'd rather not for the following reasons:

- The TV appears as an unknown display
- I'm stuck at a lower resolution than desired
- HDA Nvidia sound doesn't register

I partially solved the lower resolution by typing in some commands in the terminal but it only gets me to 1024x768. Furthermore, when I choose 768p, I start having flickering red pixels in dark portions of the screen.

Looking at the video in the link previously posted, is there any way to run Ubuntu w/o nomodeset? Thank you for reading and any help!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83567/discussion-on-question-by-efefay-ubuntu-18-04-will-not-run-w-o-nomodeset).

Comment: @karel we got moved to chat. Are you still okay to help?