# Stuck on Ubuntu's installation loading screen

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu, ubuntu-gnome, error-handling, mint

yesterday I tried to install the Ubuntu distro on my PC (Intel Core i5, NVIDIA GeForce 950m, 8gb RAM). However I wasn't able to do it. Every time it got to the prole screen with the dots in freezed. I tried to press the up arrow right before it froze:
http://prntscr.com/kytpza
My PC came with Windows 10 however I had already disabled the secure boot option. The problem is not just with Ubuntu, I tried to install Lubuntu and Linux Mint and I get the same problem. I also tried to use the bootable usb pen in other computers and worked perfectly.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Live USB for installation does not boot, visual artifacts on purple splash screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077486/live-usb-for-installation-does-not-boot-visual-artifacts-on-purple-splash-scree)