# MacBook 2.1 late 2006 issues with installation of Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, system-installation, upgrade, macbook

I rescued an old [MacBook 2.1 late 2006](https://apple-history.com/mb_late_06) 13" from my job. After a deep search of couple days I found this video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIsF96jx87A&t=539s who help me to install ubuntu 16.02 on my old macbook laptop. Now,  I've been trying to  install ubuntu 18.04, unfortunately after the installation ( it looks like everything went well during this process)   after first reboot the laptop cannot start the OS, first started with a black screen and when I forced pushing the turn on botton, I can see the system loading the OS  again, but the screen goes to  a pink-violet screen and the OS never comes up.

I really want to  make an use of this old laptop and see if i can upgrade the Ubuntu version,I will appreciate if someone can help me.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Live USB for installation does not boot, black error screen followed by visual artifacts on purple a screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077486/live-usb-for-installation-does-not-boot-black-error-screen-followed-by-visual-a)

Comment: Check out this: https://adufray.com/blog/2018/06/02/nvidia-304-127-on-bionic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add **nomodeset** to the GRUB menu  as per this [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132) post.

When Ubuntu starts to boot and you see the GRUB menu, press the letter
**e**
and then you can edit the parameters GRUB will use when booting.

Find the line with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` and replace **quiet splash** with **nomodeset** then return to booting with <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>.

Then, follow the instructions in the web link above in the section *How to permanently set kernel boot options on an installed OS (not wubi)* to make that change permanent.