# 2048MD ATI Radeon HD 5400 Series login loop - can't find in Additional Drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, amd-graphics

I was suffering from Ubuntu logo loop through startup.

I searched for solutions and I edited GRUB's option to access Ubuntu with `nomodeset` and the loop issue was gone.

But every restart I face the same problem. I have applied many solutions and the display was interrupted and I cannot find my display device on the *Additional Drivers* tab.

Ubuntu 19.04

Graphics Card 2048MD ATI Radeon HD 5400 Series

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Live USB for installation does not boot, black error screen followed by visual artifacts on a purple screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077486/live-usb-for-installation-does-not-boot-black-error-screen-followed-by-visual-a) and [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04 and newer on AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/q/815591/)

Comment: This solution doesn't work well for me.

Comment: @Ghorab Which solution doesn't work well for you? Which did you try and what were the results. Please review https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and then [edit] your post to include further information. Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 0):

Same issue as mine, I am currently using "nomodeset" in Grub as work-around.

Edit /etc/default/grub

Add "nomodeset" in the kernel options

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset"

Save in your editor (CTRL-X in nano)

Then update Grub

sudo update-grub

Then just reboot..

This is a work-around, HW acceleration will be disabled.
Unfortunately (in my case at least), this is a bug in Linux Kernel, KMS is supposed to work but is does not, and new proprietary drivers no longer support these old cards.