# Problem with installation Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, lenovo, usb-installation

I tried installing Ubuntu 18.04 on my Lenovo Legion Y540 in a dual boot with Windows 10, but however much I try, my computer always freezes after the screen that proposes to try Ubuntu/install it. It displays this error message when freezing:

[image: error-screenshot]

I tried rewriting the Ubuntu ISO on my USB drive, but it did not change anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Live USB for installation does not boot, black error screen followed by visual artifacts on a purple screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077486/live-usb-for-installation-does-not-boot-black-error-screen-followed-by-visual-a)

Answer (score 0):

you can install one software on windows 10 :unetbootin and you install ubuntu desktop on your computer (please don't copy the ubuntu desktop to your hard disk first),please open unetbootin and select ISO and select Diskimage and select the ubuntu desktop file and you may wait it install finish.Please boot your computer.And you will enter a menu called" Boot Menu ", please don't select windows boot manager,you may select another server(I don't know what server is it)and you will come in to ubuntu already because I also Lenovo want. Thank you.