# Weird glitch when trying to install Ubuntu from live USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, live-usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. I'm seeing a bizarre glitch when trying to boot from the live USB. This happens immediately after I select *Install Ubuntu* from the boot menu.

[Ubuntu Boot Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwVgt.jpg)

[image: glitch]

I tried:

1. Downloaded the ubuntu-18.04.4 ISO and made a live USB with Rufus.
2. Downloaded the ubuntu-19.10 ISO and made a live USB with Rufus.
3. I made a live USB for 18.04.04 with Universal USB
   Installer.

I see the same error each time, although the 19.10 version doesn't show the message about parsing the event.

Specs:

- OS: Windows 10.0.18363
- Manufacturer: Alienware
- System Model: Alienware Aurora R8
- CPU: Intel Core i7-8700
- BIOS: Alienware 1.0.11
- BIOS Mode: UEFI
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070

I'm not really sure what else to do. I saw one other person post about the exact same issue on the Dell website, but no on responded. He also had an Alienware machine, so maybe that is related.

Comment: Does it freeze ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Live USB for installation does not boot, black error screen followed by visual artifacts on a purple screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077486/live-usb-for-installation-does-not-boot-black-error-screen-followed-by-visual-a)

Comment: Yes it freezes @Liso. No it doesn’t unfortunately — I do not see where nomodeset is even an option

Comment: I edited the post to include a picture of the options the boot menu shows. It freezes and glitches immediately after this screen no matter what

Comment: At the grub menu you can click 'e' and tthen edit the line starting with 'linux' to add 'nomodeset' before the slashes (surrounded by space characters) like so: `... quiet splash nomodeset ---`

Comment: That worked, Thank you! @sudobus