# Display glitch when booting Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, command-line, 18.04, display, visual-artifacts

I am trying to dual-boot install Ubuntu 18.04. 
Upon booting from a USB stick and choosing either 'Try Ubuntu without installing' or 'Install Ubuntu' in the GRUB menu the screen glitches and stays that way,

[image: see pic]

I thought its a problem between the GUI and the hardware so I set the parameters 'gfxpayload' to 'text' and 'boot' to 'single' 
to boot it with the command-line (the idea being to install graphics drivers)

[image: see pic]

but it glitches just as well (although it does start the command-line.

[image: see pic]

I can get into the GRUB terminal just fine though.

[image: see pic]

I might have missed something obvious? What would be the next thing to try?

The computer and screen work well with Windows 10. The display is a Samsung C32F391 and the graphics card NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Live USB for installation does not boot, black error screen followed by visual artifacts on a purple screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077486/live-usb-for-installation-does-not-boot-black-error-screen-followed-by-visual-a)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you get to the grub menu you can add the `nomodeset` boot option. `nomodeset` tells the kernal to not load the video drivers until the X window server is started. To add this option do the following:

1. Get to the GRUB boot menu
2. Highlight the the option that you want to boot to
3. Press <kbd>e</kbd>
4. Find the line that has `linux` at the start
5. Add `nomodeset` to the end of that line
6. Press <kbd>Ctrl-x</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

Comment: Indeed  like this it boots fine. Thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome!