# Issues while booting Ubuntu 20.04 LTS after installation on Asus Tuf A15 (FA506IH) "PPM init fail"

Tags: boot, asus, acpi

This is the error I get when I boot from the installation media:

```
0365066 ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol (_ 88.PCI.GPP4.
LANI, AE_NOT_FOUND
20190916 /dswload2-169) 0365066 ACPI Error AE NOT FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/ps object-220)
0654395 ACPI Error Aborting method
0654347 ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol T2. THRM.SCP.CTYP), AE NOT FOUND 20190616 /psargs-930) TZ. SHRM. SCP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) 20190816 /psparse-529)
1.440993) tdrm:andgpuinit tundul ) ERROR# VGACON disablas andgpu kernel nodesetting.
3092070 sd 21010:01 (sdc No Caching mode page found
30929041 sd 210:0:0: (sda Assuming drive cache: units through
```

The error I get on booting after installation is complete:

```
usci_acpi USBC000:00: PPM init failed (-110)
```

I'm having these issues on the laptop I've recently bought:

Asus Tuf A15 (FA506IH)

Please help me with this.

Comment: Some ACPI errors seem to be normal and do not stop booting. Have you updated UEFI from Asus for your system? And if SSD updated SSD firmware? If you have nVidia you also need nomodeset on the linux line in grub menu. See grub menu options (not BIOS options). https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: Hi Parsa, nomodeset thing worked for me, now I'm able to boot into linux. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Live USB for installation does not boot, black error screen followed by visual artifacts on a purple screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077486/live-usb-for-installation-does-not-boot-black-error-screen-followed-by-visual-a)

Answer (score 0):

I have an Asus tuf a15 (ryzen 9 4900h + nvidia rtx 2060)
I installed Linux Mint 20.04

When you see the GRUB menu, press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit boot options, append `modeset=0` after `splash` and then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot. For me the trackpad was not working thus used wireless mouse for installation, but after installation the trackpad started working

I installed the latest kernel (5.7.15) and installed nvidia-driver-450 for nvidia graphics.

Now my system is working well with both gpu (amd remior +m nvidia rtx 2060)