# Graphics failure after changing pc

Tags: boot, graphics, intel

I boot ubuntu from an external ssd drive. Now I changed the pc to one it with a NVIVIA GeForce. While booting the graphics smeared and I can't recognize anything.

What can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Live USB for installation does not boot, black error screen followed by visual artifacts on a purple screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077486/live-usb-for-installation-does-not-boot-black-error-screen-followed-by-visual-a)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the screen?